# Error while publishing Could not find file 'bin\ar\AjaxControlToolkit.resources.dll'

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, publishing

I am trying to publish my asp.net application on shared hosting. However when I am trying to publish its giving me error

> Error  1   Copying file bin\cs\AjaxControlToolkit.resources.dll to obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\bin\cs\AjaxControlToolkit.resources.dll failed. Could not find file 'bin\cs\AjaxControlToolkit.resources.dll'.        0   0   CRM_Web_App

I have copied this project from some other folder of same PC. Also I researched it said to delete bin folder I am not very comfortable doing it. 
Please advice
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very silly of me , however got the solution 

I deleted AjaxControlToolkit from bin folder and from reference folder and added same AjaxControlToolkit reference and it published.